# Ceph install failure with ceph-deploy

Tags: cluster-computing, centos7, ceph

So ive set ceph up as described in the RHEL manual. I created the cluster 
sudo ceph-deploy --username  new mon1. After that i edit the ceph.conf and add ms_bind_ipv6 = false and public network = . After that Ive executed sudo ceph-deploy --username  install --release luminous node1 node2 node3 node4 mon1 mon2 mds1 mds2. Node 1-4 works fine, but when the script reaches node 1 and try to install itself I get this error code for nearly every package.

Example:

```
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.3-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.3-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.4-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.4-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.5-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.5-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.6-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = [mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.3-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.3-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.4-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.4-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.5-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.5-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.6-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.6-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.7-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.7-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.8-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.8-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.9-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.10-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.10-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.11-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
2:12.2.6-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.7-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.7-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.8-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.8-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.9-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.10-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
[mon1][WARNIN]                 python-rgw = 2:12.2.10-0.el7
[mon1][WARNIN]             Verfügbar: 2:python-rgw-12.2.11-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that ceph-deploy sometimes fail to setup ceph repositories on `/etc/yum.repos.d/ceph.repo`.

What I've done is to solve this issue is upload to all the destination servers `ceph.repo` file from the version you want to install, if you're installing luminous release, use something like that:

```
cat >ceph.repo<< EOF

[Ceph]
name=Ceph packages for
baseurl=http://download.ceph.com/rpm-luminous/el7/\$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
type=rpm-md
gpgkey=https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
priority=1

[Ceph-noarch]
name=Ceph noarch packages
baseurl=http://download.ceph.com/rpm-luminous/el7/noarch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
type=rpm-md
gpgkey=https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
priority=1

[ceph-source]
name=Ceph source packages
baseurl=http://download.ceph.com/rpm-luminous/el7/SRPMS
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
type=rpm-md
gpgkey=https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc
priority=1
EOF
```

To write a valid repo file (should be the same as the repo file of the "admin" node you're using to deploy the rest of the servers), send it to the destination servers:

```
scp ceph.repo dst-server:/etc/yum.repos.d/
```

And the run ceph-deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

I was ok with 2 env variables on debian(ubuntu) before install packages of ceph 14.2

```sh
export CEPH_DEPLOY_REPO_URL=https://mirror
export CEPH_DEPLOY_GPG_URL=https://mirror_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command install ceph mimic version 13.2

```
ceph-deploy install  cephmon02 cephmon03  --repo-url=http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ceph/rpm-mimic/el7/
```

Changed mimic to another version.